# On :hover transform stops working when using MUI v5 Zoom transition

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js

When using MUI transitions, in my case Zoom, the child element's on hover transform no longer works. The '&:hover' property still works, because it changes the backgroundColor, but the transform: scale(1.04) does not.

How can I make sure my cards pop into view AND then also get enlarged on hover?

(I am using Next.js with MUI v5.)

```
import { Zoom} from "@mui/material";
import { ButtonBase } from "@mui/material";

export default function CustomCard({ index }) {
    return (
        <Zoom in={true} style={{transitionDelay: index !== 0 ? '200ms' : '0ms'}}>
            <ButtonBase sx={{'&:hover': {transform: 'scale(1.04)', bgcolor: 'red'}}} >Content<ButtonBase />
        </ Zoom>
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION UPDATE:**

After some research I believe the problems lies in the inheritance chain of `transform`, from `Zoom` parent, to children. I have not gone into detail of how this works in MUI, as I was able to find a solution by completely avoiding the problem, for my particular use case.

Since the CSS property `scale()` also works without the use of transform, I just completely took out `transform` from the `&:hover`, thus avoiding the problem associated with it.

```
<Zoom in={true} style={{transitionDelay: index !== 0 ? '200ms' : '0ms'}}>
            <ButtonBase sx={{'&:hover': {scale: '1.04', bgcolor: 'red'}}} >Content<ButtonBase />
</Zoom>
```